# Does every function $f: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ which is an isometry have to be a linear function?

Tags: geometry, isometry

Does every function $f: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ which is an isometry have to be a linear function?

Give a counterexample.

I think it is a false sentence, but I cannot give a counterexample. Please help

Comment: Define isometry?

Comment: $f(x)=1+x$ is not linear. But any isometry is of the form $ax+b$.

Comment: if I (X) = X 'and I (Y) = Y', then | XY | = | X'Y '| define isometry

Comment: #Kavi Rama Murthy Why f(x)=1+x is not linear?

Comment: @Anna what is your definition of linear function?

Comment: @FormulaWriter f(x)=ax+b

Comment: @Anna Ok, this is the issue: for you a linear function is a function whose graph is a straight line, but linear function usually means a linear function between vector spaces. The answer depends on the definition to consider.

Comment: @FormulaWriter what is the other definition?

Comment: @Anna A map preserving addition and multiplication by a scalar. Look for vector spaces and linear function or linear mapping on the internet :-)

Comment: @FormulaWriter aa ok so we have f (x + y) = f (x) + f (y) and f (cx) = cf (x)

Comment: I understand everything, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be an isometry. Let us first assume $f(0)=0$(otherwise, we can just take $g(x)=f(x)-f(0)$, note that $g$ is also an isometry).
Note that $f(1)=\pm 1$. Suppose $f(1)=1$. Let $x\in\mathbb R$. Therefore, $|f(x)|=|x|$ and $|f(x)-1|=|x-1|$. It is easy to conclude from here that $f(x)=x$. Similarly, if $f(1)=-1$ then we can conclude that $f(x)=-x$. Therefore, the only isometries are the functions $f(x)=\pm x+c$ where $c\in\mathbb R$.